# Unable to get latitude and longitude in Android

Tags: android, gps

7I am unable to access the GPS using the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

When I open the app, it will die on the following:

```
locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
```

Logcat is shown below. I googled "`java.lang.SecurityException: invalid package name`" and got 7 results, so I hope I'm not in trouble :( Anyway, if anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be helpful. Also, a little background info, this is a **AOSP** rom, but I did verify from `GPS` Test app that the **GPS** is able to get a lock.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  836): java.lang.SecurityException: invalid package name
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.getLastKnownLocation(ILocationManager.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at com.derrick.rfsuite.MainActivity.processGPS(MainActivity.java:557)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at com.derrick.rfsuite.MainActivity.access$12(MainActivity.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at com.derrick.rfsuite.MainActivity$2.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
E/AndroidRuntime(  836):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have pinpointed the following as this line in the Manifest, but I don't understand what is happening

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

Comment: please check [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html)

Comment: Have you try to run this code on emulator and mock location via emulator control? It seems your code is fine, i suppose problem is because of custom rom.

Comment: what package name are you using?

Comment: Did you try getting the lat/long via the listener instead?

Comment: @dmon actually it dies when it tries to bind to the listener

Comment: @rdc I was able to get a lat/lon with your code, so my ROM must be OK. I imported your code into my project yet I get the same failure. There must be something funky going on with my manifest perhaps? I posted it above. My app was running just fine until I tried to add GPS.. weird

Comment: @user1969126 just quick question, did you used **"java"** keyword as a package name in your application? like com.java or com.xxx.java etc

Comment: @rdc no I didn't use Java. Also, I pinpointed the cause. android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in the Manifest. Although I am not sure why sharing android.uid.system would not allow it to access the GPS